# Cannot pass data from my JavaScript to my PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I click on "subcribeButton" I want it to save the value and pass that value to my PHP file. I want that PHP file to then make a post to the SQL database.

This is my js:

```js
$(".subscribeButton").on( "click", function() {

    var email = $(".subscribeInput").val();
    var isValid = isEmailValid(email);

    if(isValid){
        $(".errorMsg").css( "display", "none" );
        modal.style.display = "block";

        $.post( "save.php", { email: email });

        $(".subscribeInput").val("");

    } else {
        $(".errorMsg").css( "display", "initial" );
    };

});

$(".subscribeInput").on( "click", function() {

    $(".subscribeInput").val("");

});
```

This is my php code, I would like my php code to accept data from my js file and then post the data to my sql database:

```js
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pw";
$dbname = "db_name";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$text = $_POST['email'];

echo $text

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (email)
 VALUES ($text)";



if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The result is I'm getting the following error:

```js
POST http://flockto.it/home/save.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
send    @   jquery.js:4
ajax    @   jquery.js:4
m.(anonymous function)  @   jquery.js:4
(anonymous function)    @   email.js:13
dispatch    @   jquery.js:3
r.handle    @   jquery.js:3
```

Comment: Good!!! You have done it. Now what do you want us to do?? Is there anything wrong or is it not working???

Comment: It's giving me an error:

jquery.js:4 POST http://flockto.it/home/save.php 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery.js:4ajax @ jquery.js:4m.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:4(anonymous function) @ email.js:13dispatch @ jquery.js:3r.handle @ jquery.js:3

Comment: You see that is what I am talking about....you should add that to your question so that everyone else here (trying to help you) knows what is the exact problem. Also to avoid downvote :) :)

Comment: Thank you! will do

Comment: Make sure the url that you are calling in `$.post` is correct.  It looks like the path specified is not right.

Comment: Both files are in the same folder save.php is in the same folder as email.js

Comment: Open this URL and tell us what do you see: http://flockto.it/home/save.php

Comment: I see, the address that works is http://flockto.it/home/data/save.php

Comment: Changing the address worked

Comment: I changed $.post( "save.php", { "email": email });

to $.post( "data/save.php", { "email" : email });

And got the following message asdfasdf@asdfs.com New record created successfully

So it works, but the db didn't update so it's not 100% but I'm getting there.

Comment: see I told you its the url issue. Anyways you'll get there. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

so why not adding a callback in your ajax request so you can debug it in console or with an alert see this it may help you

```
$.post( "save.php", { "email" : email } , function(result){
   console.log(result);//here the result will display what you will echo after getting the post in your php file
});
```

so in your php file you can add this

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])){
   $text = $_POST['email'];
   echo $text;
}
//so if you check the console you will get the email
//value from your php file so then you can insert it at the DB as you want
```

Comment: This helped me get past one of the errors, thank you!! 

$.post( "save.php", { "email" : email } 

should have also been 

$.post( "data/save.php", { "email" : email }

Comment: whenever you're in a doubt with url to post to i can suggest you to put the absolute url of the page as "http://.../.../../save.php" so with this you can dubug it easily :D i'm glad cause it helped

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error.
Your code is missing the `;` at the end of this line:

```
echo $text
```

It should be:

```
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

In the js file url was wrong and quotation marks around email were missing

```js
$(".subscribeButton").on( "click", function() {

    var email = $(".subscribeInput").val();
    var isValid = isEmailValid(email);

    if(isValid){
        $(".errorMsg").css( "display", "none" );
        modal.style.display = "block";

        $.post( "data/save.php", { "email": email });

        $(".subscribeInput").val("");

    } else {
        $(".errorMsg").css( "display", "initial" );
    };

});

$(".subscribeInput").on( "click", function() {

    $(".subscribeInput").val("");

});
```

In the php file used the wrong variable

```js
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$text = $_POST['email'];

if (isset($_POST['email'])){
   $text = $_POST['email'];
   echo $text;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (email)
 VALUES ('$text')";



if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

A million thanks to everyone who replied to this thread and helped me solve the issue.